# dynamic select with rails and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a cart application where you select products from catalogue. I want to populate dynamically a few columns like the available colors based on selection, all through ajax.

This is my view when you add a new item

```
<td><%= f.collection_select(:product_id, Product.active.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select Product') %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :quantity, :size => 6 %></td>
<td><%= f.collection_select(:color_id, Color.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select Color') %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :price, :size => 8 %></td>
<td><%= f.link_to_remove "remove" %></td>
```

I want to set price and color options based on product_id value. here is what I have so far:

```
$('select#order_items_new').change(function() {
    // How to retrieve table columns based on product_id value?
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope have understood your challenge accurately. once a product is selected, a colors select will show up via ajax along with the price.

here is the product select.

```
<%= form_tag "some_form" do |f|  %>
  Choose a product:
  <%= select_tag "product_id", options_for_select( @products.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id]} ), :include_blank => true  %>
  <br>
  <div id="colors_select"></div>
<% end %>
```

when the product select is changed, ajax fires off and retrieves the products colors and price.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#product_id").live("change", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/get_colors',
      data: {
        product_id: $(this).val();
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("#colors_select").html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

don't forget to include the route to the method which returns the colors.

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'get_colors' => 'colors#get_colors'
```

a simple method which returns the partial with the colors and price. once your associations are set up, you can get a specific product's colors with: Product.find(params[:product_id]).colors

```
class ColorsController < ApplicationController

  def get_colors
    @colors = Color.all
    @price = Product.find(params[:product_id]).price
    render :partial => 'get_colors'
  end
```